# Freshly installed Wireshark with enabled non-root listen users is not able to listen

Tags: linux-mint, group, wireshark

I have Linux Mint 19 64-bit Cinnamon.

I have just installed `wireshark-gtk` with:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark-gtk
```

while installing I was asked this:

[image: wireshark non-root question]

Answering Yes as you can see, as I am the sole user of this laptop, and I don't see much of the security issue anyways enabling this. But I have a different question than this.

---

How come that when I run Wireshark from the root terminal, I can listen on my Ethernet, and when I run Wireshark as non-root, interfaces are not even listed there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the installer does not create the group for itself, do it manually with:

```
$ sudo addgroup --system wireshark
```

and add yourself to the group with:

```
$ sudo adduser $USER wireshark
```

I have then reconfigured the `wireshark-common` with:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

answering intentionally **No** first

and finally:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

answering intentionally **Yes** afterwards.

I have also logged out / in back. This is necessary.